# Checking if a string is null or not

Tags: c#, methods, null, conditional-statements

Guys I have an argument to a method.
I want to check if its null or empty string before further directing the program's execution path

My method is as

```
public void DisplayCalcQuery(string argFromQueryBuilder)
{
    if ((argFromQueryBuilder.Trim() != null) || (argFromQueryBuilder.Trim() != ""))
    {
        //notify closure of query builder
        _QueryBuilderIsOpen = false;
        UserBuiltQueries.Add(argFromQueryBuilder);
        //displayng the user built query(queries) on the stack panel meant to display it. 
        var lastItem = UserBuiltQueries[UserBuiltQueries.Count - 1];
        //removing all $signs from the obtained string
        lastItem = lastItem.Replace(@"$", "");
        addBuiltCheck(lastItem); 
    }
    else
    {
        //notify closure of query builder
        _QueryBuilderIsOpen = false;
    }
}
```

However, even when the string is being `""`
The program is executing the IF (which I do not want to happen).

Comment: Use `String.IsNullOrEmpty(yourString)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your intention is to check `Whitespace` you need to Use the `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` method

Try This:

```
if(!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(argFromQueryBuilder))
{
  //do here

}
```

**Complete Code:**

```
public void DisplayCalcQuery(string argFromQueryBuilder)
{
if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(argFromQueryBuilder))
{
    //notify closure of query builder
    _QueryBuilderIsOpen = false;
    UserBuiltQueries.Add(argFromQueryBuilder);
    //displayng the user built query(queries) on the stack panel meant to display it. 
    var lastItem = UserBuiltQueries[UserBuiltQueries.Count - 1];
    //removing all $signs from the obtained string
    lastItem = lastItem.Replace(@"$", "");
    addBuiltCheck(lastItem); 
}
else
{
    //notify closure of query builder
    _QueryBuilderIsOpen = false;
}
```

}

Comment: Please note that `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` was first introduced in .NET Framework 4.

Answer (score 9):

Use **String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace**  as mentioned below

```
public void DisplayCalcQuery(string argFromQueryBuilder)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(argFromQueryBuilder))
    {
        //notify closure of query builder
        _QueryBuilderIsOpen = false;
        UserBuiltQueries.Add(argFromQueryBuilder);
        //displayng the user built query(queries) on the stack panel meant to display it. 
        var lastItem = UserBuiltQueries[UserBuiltQueries.Count - 1];
        //removing all $signs from the obtained string
        lastItem = lastItem.Replace(@"$", "");
        addBuiltCheck(lastItem); 
    }
    else
    {
        //notify closure of query builder
        _QueryBuilderIsOpen = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: OP wants to perform operation when string is  not empty

Answer (score 6):

Use [`String.IsNullOrEmpty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx) which is precisely designed for checking whether a value is a null reference or a reference to a 0-length string - although it's *not* designed for checking for an all-whitespace string. [`String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx) will handle that, but it's only available from .NET 4 upwards. It's important to distinguish (in your mind) between an *empty* string (one with a length of 0) and an all-whitespace string - your question *asks* about an empty string, but the you're trimming the string in code before checking for emptiness, which suggests you actually just want to know whether it's all-whitespace or not.

The result of `Trim` will *never* be a null reference, although it might be a reference to an empty string. Those are very different things. It's not clear why you've got an `||` clause either, as `Trim()` could never return *both* a reference to an empty string *and* a null reference.

Additionally, if you're really interested in the trimmed value, you should probably use that consistently through the code - at which point you may need to separate the checking for nullity and the checking for an empty string anyway:

```
if (arg == null)
{
    // Whatever
}
string trimmed = arg.Trim();
if (arg == "")
{
    // Whatever
}
```

Or you could take the extra hit of checking for whitespace and still trimming:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(arg))
{
    // Whatever - make sure you return in here,
    // to avoid calling Trim on a null reference
}
string trimmed = arg.Trim();
// Whatever
```

The latter is cleaner if you're using .NET 4 - it's unlikely that the performance difference will be significant.

Finally, if it's *valid* for a caller to pass in a reference to an empty (or all-whitespace) string, but not valid for them to pass in a null reference, consider handling those situations separately:

```
if (arg == null)
{
    throw new ArgumentNullException("...");
}
string trimmed = arg.Trim();
if (arg == "")
{
    // Whatever
}
```

Comment: damn it. you beat me to it :)

Comment: Wouldn't `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` be more of what he intended to get?

Comment: @JonSkeet: in method `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()`  s is Caital in Space

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi: Thanks, fixed. That's pretty odd, IMO - I very usually see whitespace as a single word, rather than hyphenated as it is in MSDN. Ah well :)

Comment: @AnoushkaSeechurn: Please don't add comments on unrelated questions just to attract attention.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend:

```
String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()
```

as it check string is null, empty or contains only white-spaces.

while `String.IsNullOrEmpty` will not check white-spaces.